How to pass variable to TimerTask run()?
Can I change a variable in the run() method that is defined in the code above?
boolean flag = false;
        
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        flag = true; // error
        logger.info("flag changed");
    }
};
    
timer.schedule(task, 30_000);

while(true) {
    if(flag) break;
    ...
}


Make the flag an AtomicBoolean then set the value instead of re-assigning.

And then use while (!flag.get()) { instead of an infinite loop with a break if flag is true.

@matt AtomicBoolean works, got it

@rozerro If that solution works for you, post an Answer to your own Question for posterity.

By the way, Timer and TimerTask are legacy, as noted in their Javadoc. Learn to use the Executors framework instead. Define your task as a Runnable or Callable, submit instances to an ExecutorService. Capture returned Future to track completion.

@BasilBourque didn't find the word "legasy" or "deprecated" in the corresponding javadoc

If you check the Timer documentation there is a paragraph about how a ScheduledExecutor is equivalent or better.

You probably don‘t want to use busy waiting. You may look for a completely different synchronization mechanism.

@rozerro Quoting the Javadoc… API Note:
Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads, accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing TimerTask (just implement Runnable). Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.

The following solution works:
AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(); //initial value false
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        flag.set(true);
    }
};
    
timer.schedule(task, 30_000);

while(!flag.get()) {
    ...
}

